# Matlines getting in linear regression model in R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, prediction, confidence-interval

I am running a toy prediction model that looks like this:

```
model1 <- lm(weight ~ age)
plot(predict(model1), weight)
pred.frame <- data.frame(age = 4:20)
pp <- predict (model1, int = "p", newdata = pred.frame)
pc <- predict (model1, int = "c", newdata = pred.frame)
plot(age, weight, ylim = range(weight, pp, na.rm = TRUE))
pred.model1 <- pred.frame$age
matlines(pred.model1, pc, lty = c(1,2,2), col = 'black')
matlines(pred.model1, pp, lty = c(1,3,3), col = 'black')
```

however, the graphic I get has the pc and pp lines cut:

[image: plot]

tried a couple computers and I keep getting the same result. both are running the latest version of mac os with mavericks, with quartz generating the graphics.

any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Try it again with `pred.frame <- data.frame(age = 4:40)`

Comment: If you want to extend the x-axis down to 4, set `xlim=c(4,max(age))` in `plot()`. With base graphics, once `plot` is called, the limits will not be changed to `matplot` will not change the view window even if it has points outside the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the data range on which you carry out your predictions is restricted to 4 to 20 years, given that your code reads

```
pred.frame <- data.frame(age = 4:20)
```

Try it again with

```
pred.frame <- data.frame(age = 4:40)
```

Comment: you got it @coffeinjunky, my range should have been 23:28 . thanks a ton

Comment: No problem. Easy to miss. Feel free to accept this answer so that others see the problem is solved.